# Ignore access token in useEffect dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, access-token, use-effect

I want to fetch data on initial render of a component.  The fetch requires an access token which is stored in context and accessible via a custom hook.  When the access token is refreshed, I don't want useEffect to run again.  I can not useMemo the access token because on the same page, I have a save button that does a fetch also.  On save, I want to use the latest access token in case it has been refreshed.  So in short, how can I ignore the accessToken dependency in useEffects but still use the latest value when the useEffect runs?

```
  const accessToken = useAccessToken();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const taskResult = await fetch("/tasks", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      setTasks(taskResult);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);  // eslint warning because it wants accessToken as a dependency
```

Comment: Looks like you want to _close_ the access token with your fetchData function. Move the fetchData function out of useEffect and wrap it with useCallback. Then you should be able to use the returned callback in a useEffect call without having your token as a dependency.

Comment: Won't the token be a dependency for the callback which leads to the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure that data was fetched exactly ones using flag saved in another state. So this what I would personally do:

```
const accessToken = useAccessToken();
const [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setFetched(true);
      const taskResult = await fetch("/tasks", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
      setTasks(taskResult);
    };
    if(!fetched) fetchData();
  }, [accessToken, fetched]);
```

This way you will always have the latest accessToken for data fetch.